# Xively and Node-Red

Tags: node.js, xively, node-red

I'm fairly new at all this but have muddled my way to getting my Arduino to post values to a Xively stream I've named "Lux and Temp."  Three values; count, lux, and temperature.

Now what I want to do is take those values and do something with them using Node-Red.
http://nodered.org

I have Node-Red up and running, but I'll be danged if I can figure out how to parse the data from the Xively API feed.  https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1823833592

Sadly, I don't have enough reputation points to be able to actually post the data it returns to here, since it has more than 3 URLs embedded in the data.  It's a LONG string of data too.  ;)

I'm just stumped though as to how to write the function to extract the parts I want.

My initial want is to make a simple Twitter feed out of it.  Something like;

"Count 40, Lux 30, Temp 78.3"

I'll eventually want to recycle the code for other things like making my RasPi do something; maybe a display or some LEDs.  In either case I need to parse the data and build various messages with it.

Anybody have any experience with the Node-Red functions that can walk me through a solution?  The Node-Red site is pretty awesome, but I think it assumes I'm a MUCH more experienced user than I really am.  It gives hints, but frankly about all I know is fairly basic Arduino and trivial level Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it shouldn't be too tricky, but try putting this in a function block:

```
var newPayload = "";
var count, lux, temp;

var data = msg.payload.datastreams;

for (var i = 0 ; i< data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].id === 'Count') {
    count = data[i].current_value;
  }else if (data[i].id === 'Lux') {
    lux = data[i].current_value;
  } else if (data[i].id === 'Temp') {
    temp = data[i].current_value;
  }
}

newPayload = util.format('Count: %s, Lux: %s, Temp: %s', count, lux, temp);

msg.payload = newPayload;

return msg;
```

You may need to add a msg.payload = JSON.parse(msg.payload); to the start if however your getting the feed from xively is not already considered to be json.
[edit]
You could also just run the flow through a JSON parse node. (I always forget the converter nodes)

You should be able to wire that to a twitter output node.

Comment: Awesome!  I did need to add the msg.payload = JSON.parse(msg.payload); to the start, but it's working!

Even better, your example is easy enough to read that I think I understand it well enough to be able to adapt it.

Thank you very much,